# Differrent interaction of Array() constructor and using Array Literal

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was using Array(n).fill([]) to initialize a dynamic 2d array and using push to insert. It kept inserting into all the sub-arrays. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Here are the two different codes.

```
let n=3
let madeWithConstructor = new Array(n).fill([]);
madeWithConstructor[0].push(3);
```

this will insert value 3 in **all** sub-arrays.

```
let n=3
let madeWithLiteral = [];
for(let i=0;i<n;i++){
    madeWithLiteral.push([]);
}
madeWithLiteral[0].push(3);
madeWithLiteral;
```

this gives the **desired output** i.e. only the sub-array at index 0 = 3

Comment: The same object referencing for all the indexes.  The function `fill` is using the same object for the N indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The same object reference for all the indexes. The function `Array.fill` is using the same object for the N indexes.

You can use the function [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to initialize each index with different objects (Arrays).

```js
let n = 3
let madeWithConstructor = Array.from({
  length: n
}, () => []);

madeWithConstructor[0].push(3);

console.log(JSON.stringify(madeWithConstructor))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first piece of code is roughly equivalent to this:

```
function makeArray(len, defaultValue) {
  const arr = new Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    arr.push(defaultValue);
  }
  reutrn arr;
}

const arr = makeArray(n, []);
```

That means the same array reference is used for each index in the array.

Another way to do what you want is something like:

```
const arr = Array(n).fill(null).map(_ => []);
```